# GoogleApiCalendar dont open the redirecting window in the line AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate my java app with GoogleApiCalendar, it works in my local machine, but when I deploy my app in my test server,  the redirection after this line Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user"); does not works.
It's not that the verification fails with the test server, it's that the redirection window doesn't open at all. The process just hangs there, waiting for a response. It works correctly on my local machine and opens the window, and even allows me to access the test machine credentials, which are added to the console.cloud.
This is my code:
`InputStream in = new FileInputStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);

```
    if (in == null) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
    }

    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

    // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder( HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
        .setAccessType("offline")
        .setApprovalPrompt("force")
        .build();


    LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(7777).build();
    
    
    //It stops in here
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    

    //returns an authorized Credential object.
    return credential;`
```

Sorry for my English and thank you.

I have my test server registered on the credentials and ports are available. Also I have the browser permission to redirecting.
I tried to set the host like this too, but it doesnt work:
LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setHost(my_server_url).setPort(7777).build();

Comment: If your running that on a server then the authorization window is going to open on the server.   Thats installed application code not web application  hens the "AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp"